# def coming up as invalid syntax

Tags: python

I am having trouble with defining variables in python, i am currently a beginner and i would like some help with this:

```
def tempc_f():
   C = input("Give me a temp in Celcius and I'll convert it to Fahrenheit: ")
   F = float(9)/float(5)*float(C) + float(32)
   print(str(C),"Degrees Celcius in Fahrenheit is",str(F))   
def tempf_c():
   F1 = input("Give me a temp in Fahrenheit and i'll convert it to Celcius: ")
    C1 = float(F1)-float(32)*float(9)/float(5)
    print(str(F1),"Degrees Fahrenheit in Celcius is",str(C1))
def tempf_k():
   F2 = input("Give me a temp in Fahrenheit and i'll convert it to Kelvin: ")
    K2 = (float(F2)-float(32)/float(1.8)+float(273.15)
def tempc_k()
    C2 = input("Give me a temp in Celcius and I'll convert it to Kelvin: ")
    K3 = float(C2+273.15)
    print(str(C2),"Degrees Celcius in Fahrenheit is",str(K3))
def tempk_c():
    K4 = input("Give me a temp in Kelvin and I'll convert it to Celcius: ")
    C3 = float(K4)-float(273)
    print(str(K4),"Degrees Kelvin in Celcius is",str(C3))
```

Whenever I try to run this code it comes up in an error saying...

```
file: 'file:///Users/student/Desktop/Zach%27s%20programs/tututu.py'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'E0001:invalid syntax (<string>, line 2)'
at: '2,1'
source: 'pylint'
code: 'E0001'
```

It says that my def's are undefined, what's wrong?

Comment: Close your parentheses on the previous line.

Comment: There's syntax errors in this code, like `tempc_k` has no trailing `:` and the indentation is all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
def tempc_k()
    C2 = input("Give me a temp in Celcius and I'll convert it to Kelvin: ")
    K3 = float(C2+273.15)
    print(str(C2),"Degrees Celcius in Fahrenheit is",str(K3))
```

You are missing a colon at the end of the function name

Comment: There's also rampant indentation issues.

Comment: that's why typo questions shouldn't be answered. A good IDE can answer those.

Comment: Also `K2 = (float(F2)-float(32)/float(1.8)+float(273.15)` has an unmatched `(`.